# Monitoring HTTP Traffic in Kubernetes

Tags: http, kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring, servicemesh

I need to monitor HTTP traffic within my Kubernetes cluster. Specifically, I need response times, status codes, etc.

Currently, I am using a service mesh (Open Service Mesh) for this purpose. But, is there a lightweight solution that only allows monitoring (without security layer etc.) ?

Thanks for all ideas!

Comment: What kind of cluster do you use? Is it created by kubeadm or managed by cloud GKE, EKS, AKS?

Comment: It is a self-hosted cluster. I am not quite sure if it is administrated with kubeadm or not.

Comment: @bennex what did you end up using? It is a genuine question every SRE needs to know